# A separated link for every article (bootsrap modal, django, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, angularjs, django

I have a landing page with a list of articles. Users can open every article in a modal window. The problem is that in this way I don't have a possibility to share a link for a specific article. I am trying to find a solution similar to how facebooks newsfeed is working- when you open a picture in the newsfeed, the link is changing and you can copy this link and share it with anybody else.

[image]

My website is made on django (python) and it's using bootstrap for modal. I heard that the solution can be in using a JS framework like Angular or similar. Unfortunately I am not so familiarized with JavaScript. What solutions can I find for this issue?

Comment: Are you using ajax modals?

Comment: I am using bootstrap. Sincerely, I don't  really understand how does it work (modal). We had a front-end developer, but now he is no more working for our project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just make a separate page displaying individual articles? I know that you already had the modal but by sharing the url that displays the individual page url people could read what's being shared without other useless contents and also make your life easier. The unique identifier could be the article id or a slug.

Comment: This is exactly what I will do if I don't find a solution for modal.

Comment: You could still make it work with modal, just use something like a query string in your url to identify the article, but it would make things complicated and unnecessary. And if you think about it, url is probably the only thing you could count on.